# Node.js: Is there any documentation about the process.env variable

Tags: node.js, process

I use `process.env` a little in my program, it seems this variable have nothing to do with my program， without it my app could work well, too.

So how can I fully use the `process.env`? Is there any document or tutorial about it?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try this link http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Then you can make a small program in nodeJS:

```
console.log(process.env)
```

And run it

```
$ node myProgram.js

{ TERM_PROGRAM: 'iTerm.app',
  TERM: 'xterm',
  SHELL: '/bin/bash',
  CLICOLOR: '1',
  TMPDIR: '/var/folders/ff/59np25p96x95hpgbtsv3r6zr0000gn/T/',
  Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render: '/tmp/launch-LIiu0r/Render',
  OLDPWD: '/Users/hermanjunge',
  USER: 'hermanjunge',
  COMMAND_MODE: 'unix2003',
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/tmp/launch-XOMy7j/Listeners',
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: '0x1F5:0:0',
  Apple_Ubiquity_Message: '/tmp/launch-jiZQH0/Apple_Ubiquity_Message',
  LSCOLORS: 'ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad',
  PATH: '/Users/hermanjunge/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin',
  PWD: '/tmp',
  ITERM_PROFILE: 'hermanjunge',
  SHLVL: '1',
  COLORFGBG: '7;0',
  HOME: '/Users/hermanjunge',
  ITERM_SESSION_ID: 'w1t4p0',
  LOGNAME: 'hermanjunge',
  LC_CTYPE: 'UTF-8',
  DISPLAY: '/tmp/launch-HCtQeC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0',
  _: '/usr/local/bin/node' }
```

Then, we learned that we can get elements from the environment we are running our app. Like, for example:

```
console.log(process.env.PWD);
```

Which returns

```
/tmp
```

And so on...

Comment: Can I add or change some field?

Comment: Run your program with the variable of interest. Example: `$ MYVAR=somevalue node myProgram.js`, then access it by its name: `console.log(process.env.MYVAR);`

Comment: If I want add more than one variable what should I do?Is there more tips like this?Where can I learn them?

Comment: This way: `$ MYVAR=somevalue OTHERVAR=othervalue node myProgram.js`

Comment: You can learn a lot reading the nodeJS docs, and I advice you to play a lot with tests programs using `console.log()`.

Comment: Or you can use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to learn about how your node app works.

Comment: This could have been added to node in later versions, but you can now do:
node -p process.env
No need to save a file first

Comment: Running a test program is not documentation, unless it can be run on all possible versions on all possible operating systems.

Comment: I think you missed the first line of the answer @giorgiosironi, where a link to the documentation is pointed. I'm sorry that a complementary example has bothered you that much!!! :-)

Comment: Sorry, the frustration of ever-changing env variables :) This is not a Node.js responsibility: most of them come from the underlying OS I guess.

Answer (score 3):

There is no documentation for the variables of `process.env` since it based on your environment. (Surprise).

When an operation system (OS, Linux, Win, or other), starts a process it's passing it environment variables that the process can read.

using `process.env` you can read the variables that passed to your programs by the OS.

Usually, NodeJS projects are using `process.env` for two things:

1. Things that need to be changed between environment. For e.g. development, testing, and production. You don't want to connect to real DB during development, and you don't want to show all `console.log` on production.
2. To keep secret. It's unsafe top keep API, tokens, and private keys on Git. So you save set it by using environment variable before starting the app.

*Pro tip:* There is another way. To define things in `.env` file. At this file to your `.gitignore`, and use the npm module `dotenv`

Comment: Loren's West config might be a better alternative in 2022 year. https://www.npmjs.com/package/config (there are few people referred pm2). From my perspective different config files should be defined for each environment and by just supplying right env name we can run app with different env variables. Although it seems dotenv allows only single .env file, going further adding different scripts for start app under different envs in package,json is not easy as it should be. Just a feedback from the quick overview.