# Node.js child_process execution of Python script causing errors importing modules

Tags: python, node.js, electron, child-process

Using `child_process.spawn` in `node.js` to execute a python script via an electron app (node.js). If I run the python script on terminal (macOS) there are no problems, but, using `node.js` and:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
let ls = spawn('python', ['runserver.py','--help'], {
  cwd: __dirname,
  detached: true
})
```

I get errors from `python` of failed module imports, such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 17, in <module>
    from queue import Queue
ImportError: No module named queue
```

I've already tried setting different environments with no luck.

**Edit:**

Here are the logs of `sys.path`:

- from code execution via `child_process`

  ```
  [
    '/Users/xAlien95/Desktop/test.app/Contents/Resources/app',
    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC'
  ]
  ```
- from code execution via terminal

  ```
  [
    '/Users/xAlien95/Desktop/test.app/Contents/Resources/app',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
  ]
  ```

So, in terminal it's using the `homebrew` downloaded Python framework.  How could I ensure the same will happen in the `node.js` app?

Comment: Have the python script print/log sys.path.  Make sure the python install is present. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/where-is-pythons-sys-path-initialized-from

Comment: @StephenRauch, thanks for your suggestion, I edited the question. Is there a way to easily set that environment in nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to have python find different libraries is to use the environment  variable `PYTHONPATH`.  You can set this in node.js using `process.env.PYTHONPATH`

([DOCS](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)) ([SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058954/node-js-is-there-any-documentation-about-the-process-env-variable))

For the specific case of wanting to run the `homebrew` installed python, the python executable should be available at:

```
let ls = spawn(process.env.HOMEBREW_PREFIX + '/bin/python', ['runserver.py','--help'], {
    ...
```

If `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` is not available in`process.env`, and the path to the desired python is known, it can be hard-coded into the spawn:

```
let ls = spawn(/*<Where my python lives>*/ + '/bin/python', ['runserver.py','--help'], {
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `PYTHONPATH` or `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` in my `process.env` Object. But it works if I put `'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python'`. Just edit your answer with "if process.env.HOMEBREW_PREFIX isn't available, just put the full string path before" and I'll mark it as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, so in my case too, there are no PYTHONPATH or HOMEBREW_PREFIX and even with the absolute path, I got the same problem.
I am not sure I have the right path although. Sometimes I got : spawn ENOTDIR Error ! @xAlien95 please help